# Why won't React production build run on the browser?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to build my react app using react's build tool. When I try to "npm start", the app works fine.

```
npm start
```

On http://localhost:3000 => I can access the application.

[image]

But when I build the application and try to access "index.html" file on the build folder, it doesn't work and I encounter with a white blank screen.

```
npm run build
```

http://myreact-app/build/index.html => White blank screen.

This is the build folder which has been created after run npm run build.

[image]

And this is the **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <title>React App</title>
    <link href="/static/css/main.9a0fe4f1.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript> 
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.46d8cd76.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Am I doing something wrong? Can't I access the built index.html file on my apache web server?

Comment: @Sulthan I've added. I am also trying to figure out it but it is the output of "npm run build". No error in the console

Comment: Does `main.js` contain only your code or does it also includes all dependencies? That should be trivial to check.

Comment: In case this helps anyone... my problem was that my server wasn't allowing access to the static files requested by `index.html`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Probably you've not noticed yet but I don't think your html file is able to import css and script files correctly. When I look at your file structure, I see the everything about build is under the build folder. But in your html file, there are slashes ("/") before the file paths. That's why browser is looking for those files under the parent of the "build". Try to remove slashes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no">
      <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
      <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"><link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
      <title>React App</title>
      <style></style>
      <link href="static/css/main.65027555.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body
      <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
      <div id="root"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/main.316f1156.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And above mentioned `"homepage": "."` in `package.json` file adds `.` in front of slash so it becomes `./static/js/main.123.js` which does the same trick

Comment: The network console in browser should be one of the first places to check anyway. The file loading error is probably there.

Comment: why are the slashes added, any proper way to avoid them?

Answer (score 46):

The above problem can be overcome if you add

```
"homepage":".",
```

in your `package.json`. This is not official but a good hack to follow.

https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/1487

Comment: When linking some reference, you can post something useful like the most important part of the post, so your answer can be more valuable...

Comment: Below is the source for above comment. May be it will help someone else. https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#serving-the-same-build-from-different-paths

Comment: Adding the updated link here : https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#serving-the-same-build-from-different-paths

Answer (score 26):

To fix this problem go to your `build` folder then you will see `manifest.json` file, open it and you will see your `manifest.json` have:

```
"start_url": ".",
```

change it to

```
"start_url": "/",
```

there is alternative way to fix the problem:

before your react project build go to your `package.json` file and specify `homepage` property with `.` value or maybe with your site base url, see example:

```
{
   ....
   "homepage": ".",
   ......
}
```

Comment: Adding `"homepage": "."` is what worked for me. I can see in the index.html file built it prefixed all the links with a '.' which was exactly the problem I was having, thank you!

Comment: Can confirm. Changing start_url is not working. Changing homepage in package.json works for me.

Answer (score 7):

If nothing of above works. Maybe the problem is that you are using `react-router-dom` and the routes needs a special compilation generating individual `htmls` for each page that exists in your `router` config.

Ref:
[I'm using create-react-app and I need to open build/index.html in browser directly without a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45878542/im-using-create-react-app-and-i-need-to-open-build-index-html-in-browser-direct)

In summary you need to use `<HashRouter>` instead `<Router>` and a `<Switch>` wrapper to your routes. For example:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path='/' component={WelcomePage} />
  <Route exact path='/game' component={GamePage} />
</Switch>
```

Consider that your routes will change to:

```
http://localhost:3000/#/ -> Root page
http://localhost:3000/#/game -> Other page
```

Comment: `HashRouter` worked perfectly, with `react-router-dom`.

Comment: I changed `BrowserRouter` to `HashRouter` and it worked! Thanks

Answer (score 5):

you should try use the serve package [here](https://github.com/zeit/serve) to run single page app.

- `npm install -g serve` to install globally
- `serve help` to see help texts
- `serve --single build` to serve single page app. I server will be started from which you can access your react app

Comment: can we use build directory to host the server?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install local server plugin/extenstion.

If you are vscode user then search live server extension and install it. Then there will be "Go live" option in bottom of your editor.

For other editor user (atom/sublime) search for live server plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the reason that the content is not served is because the command of "serve -s" was executed from outside of the build directory. The correct way is to go into the build directory then execute "serve -s" from therein.

Answer (score 0):

I had an `index.php` in the webroot which prevented my app from running `index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

I use **HashRouter** instead **BrowserRouter** & also need to add **/#** infront of every url like this:

```
href={`/#/blogs/${slug}`}
```

this works for me , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<HashRouter>` instead of `<Router>`, and don't forget to `import {HashRouter}`.

Comment: can you please montion what is the difference ?