# Why running index.html won't work for a `create-react-app` build?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am new to `create-react-app`.
I want to know why opening the `index.html` form a build does not work ??
I know to serve a build `serve -s build` should be used, but I want to know why a build react app can’t be started without serving.

I will explain further:
What I do is...

1. `create-react-app helloworld`
2. Make some code changes and verify that app is running ok.
3. `npm run build` or `yarn run build` ... Now I will have my `./build` directory created with `index.html` in it.
4. Now I just open `index.html` in browser and it won't work.

I want to understand why this does not work? 
Why I have to serve the build to make it work?

Comment: Checkout this answer- the most upvoted. might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/44371294

Comment: I'm having the same issue. How did you fix it?

Comment: still a great question @Gaurav51289

Answer (score 13):

Following answer was given on similar topic by some guy on reddit

> The project was built assuming it is hosted at the server root.
>
> To override this, specify the homepage in your package.json.
>
> I wouldn't recommended it but you can add the following to
>   package.json to run it directly from your file server -
>
> "homepage":"./"

https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/5iya27/why_open_up_indexhtml_wont_workcreatereactapp/

also, You may want so serve the app on some kind of server
more info here:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment
and here:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build

Comment: TL,DR; Add `"homepage": "."` to your `package.json` to be able to run `index.html` locally

Answer (score 4):

For those using react-router-dom, you can use `<HashRouter>` instead of `<BrowserRouter>`. It should look like this:

```
<HashRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact component={ Main } />
  </Switch>
</HashRouter>
```

Comment: Thanks man, Works for me. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51976069/6585476) are a useful resource about the difference between `BrowserRouter` and `HashRouter`

Answer (score 1):

For react-router apps, there is a hack. Just make a `<Route/>` with path "/index.html" going to a suitable component.

`<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
 <Route path="/index.html" component={Home} />`

Comment: That didn't work for me. Still get a blank page when I open up index.html in browser.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. How did you fix it?