# Basic `ReactDOM.render` example does not display anything

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I’m following this React tutorial and I can’t get `index.html` to connect with my `index.js`. I haven’t installed anything related to Node or something in command prompt yet.

`index.js`

```
ReactDOM.render(<p>Hi, my name is Bob!</p>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

`index.html`

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script src="index.js" type="text/babel"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

I tried to display *“Hello, everyone!”* when I open my `index.html` file. But nothing appears. I just get a blank HTML page.

Comment: You probably need `react-dom` cdn as well.

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`), read any errors. The dev tools provide a **Network** tab. Are the scripts _correctly loaded and found_ (e.g. HTTP 200 response)? If not, are they blocked by an extension or the browser? Using the `file:` might not work; use an HTTP server instead.

Comment: Looks like you're looking at the file on your disk inside of VSCode instead of the current status of the HTML as rendered on the client through your browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React doesn't allow this interaction out of the box unless you set `homepage: ""` in your `package.json` for [routing purposes](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1094#issuecomment-262770042).

A similar overflow question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46458995/why-running-index-html-wont-work-for-a-create-react-app-build)

But you said you don't have Node.js installed yet. You're going to need that to use React and install its node package dependencies. You can download that [here](https://nodejs.org/en) and set up a npm environment which gets set up automatically with the `npx create-react-app` command.

Conventionally, you're supposed to run React apps in development by using the command `npm start` and the line `"start": "react-scripts start"` in your `package.json`

If you've finished you're project then run `npm run build` and then `npx serve -s build`, but all you need is a JavaScript runtime environment so there are [other ways to deploy](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/)