# Deploying React app to production returns "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, vercel

**Problem**

I have an axios call at "/artists", that gets a list of artists returned as an array of JSON. It works in development. However, in production it outputs an HTML element that says **You need to enable Javascript** because the data returned from "/artists" is undefined (proof of it below):

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
        <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="./logo192.png" />
        <link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json" />
        <title>React App</title>
        <link href="./static/css/main.5eece21d.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script>
            !(function (e) {
                function t(t) {
                    for (var n, f, i = t[0], l = t[1], p = t[2], c = 0, s = []; c < i.length; c++) (f = i[c]), Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o, f) && o[f] && s.push(o[f][0]), (o[f] = 0);
                    for (n in l) Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(l, n) && (e[n] = l[n]);
                    for (a && a(t); s.length; ) s.shift()();
                    return u.push.apply(u, p || []), r();
                }
                function r() {
                    for (var e, t = 0; t < u.length; t++) {
                        for (var r = u[t], n = !0, i = 1; i < r.length; i++) {
                            var l = r[i];
                            0 !== o[l] && (n = !1);
                        }
                        n && (u.splice(t--, 1), (e = f((f.s = r[0]))));
                    }
                    return e;
                }
                var n = {},
                    o = { 1: 0 },
                    u = [];
                function f(t) {
                    if (n[t]) return n[t].exports;
                    var r = (n[t] = { i: t, l: !1, exports: {} });
                    return e[t].call(r.exports, r, r.exports, f), (r.l = !0), r.exports;
                }
                (f.m = e),
                    (f.c = n),
                    (f.d = function (e, t, r) {
                        f.o(e, t) || Object.defineProperty(e, t, { enumerable: !0, get: r });
                    }),
                    (f.r = function (e) {
                        "undefined" != typeof Symbol && Symbol.toStringTag && Object.defineProperty(e, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: "Module" }), Object.defineProperty(e, "__esModule", { value: !0 });
                    }),
                    (f.t = function (e, t) {
                        if ((1 & t && (e = f(e)), 8 & t)) return e;
                        if (4 & t && "object" == typeof e && e && e.__esModule) return e;
                        var r = Object.create(null);
                        if ((f.r(r), Object.defineProperty(r, "default", { enumerable: !0, value: e }), 2 & t && "string" != typeof e))
                            for (var n in e)
                                f.d(
                                    r,
                                    n,
                                    function (t) {
                                        return e[t];
                                    }.bind(null, n)
                                );
                        return r;
                    }),
                    (f.n = function (e) {
                        var t =
                            e && e.__esModule
                                ? function () {
                                      return e.default;
                                  }
                                : function () {
                                      return e;
                                  };
                        return f.d(t, "a", t), t;
                    }),
                    (f.o = function (e, t) {
                        return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e, t);
                    }),
                    (f.p = "./");
                var i = (this.webpackJsonpspotify = this.webpackJsonpspotify || []),
                    l = i.push.bind(i);
                (i.push = t), (i = i.slice());
                for (var p = 0; p < i.length; p++) t(i[p]);
                var a = l;
                r();
            })([]);
        </script>
        <script src="./static/js/2.2cc1353a.chunk.js"></script>
        <script src="./static/js/main.0515e6b9.chunk.js"></script>
    </body>
```

This error appears because in my action creator:

```
export const fetchArtists = () => async (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
    const response = await axios.get<Artist[]>("/artists");
    console.log(response);
    dispatch<FetchArtistsAction>({
        type: ActionTypes.FETCH_ARTISTS,
        payload: response.data,
    });
};
```

**console.log(response) output in production mode :**

[image: https://gyazo.com/d603fd9e2ef06eac594a3cedc5caba1a]

**console.log(response) output in development mode:**

[image]

**My site**

https://spotify-eight.vercel.app/

The page would load, then it will give you a blank page because of the /artists route call. It will you the production output above, causing the error.

[image]

**Backend code**

**My src/backend/artistRoutes.ts**

```
router.get("/", async (req: RequestWithBody, res: Response) => {
    const artists = await Artists.find({});
    res.send(artists);
});
```

My **src/backend/index.ts**, which generates the **src/backend/build** when compiled:

```
.....
.....
mongoose.connect(process.env.mongoURI, { useNewUrlParser: true });

//Models
require("./models/Artists");
//Routes
app.use("/artists", artistsRoutes);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

//Production
const path = require("path");
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../../../build")));
    app.get("*", function (req, res) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../../../build"));
    });
}
app.listen(PORT);
```

Overview of my **project's folder structure**:

[image]

I have set up my **production environment variables** in Vercel, my hosting site:

[image]

**Other solutions I've tried from other posts with no avail:**

[I am getting error in console "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app." reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50286927/i-am-getting-error-in-console-you-need-to-enable-javascript-to-run-this-app-r)

[Why won't React production build run on the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44371052/why-wont-react-production-build-run-on-the-browser)

1. In package.json adding a `"homepage": ".",`
2. In manifest.json, Changing start URL  `"start_url": ".",` to  `"start_url": "/",`
3. Adding a proxy server. I already have it enabled ever since I started deployment.  `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"`

Comment: You can try to add index.html as a third argument res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../build', 'index.html')) and you can try to play with path "../../"(or "../") maybe production deploy do something unpredictable with paths...

Comment: Thanks for the response @Alexey, I;ve tried it with ../, ../../ , ../../../ and ../../../../ but it does not work!

Comment: Found solution to this? I am also stuck

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you serve react static files using nginx or apache.
If so, try look in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/the-config-file`, for react it usually has this line:

```
  try_files $uri /index.html;
```

What it does is, if someone access https://spotify-eight.vercel.app/artists, try serve https://spotify-eight.vercel.app/artists/index.html, if not found serve rootPath/index.html. I think thats what is happening.

I suggest serve the api endpoint in another port other than :80 so static files and endpoints can be differentiate easily. Dont change the nginx config try_files directive because your react app wont serve paths correctly otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the response! However, I am not using apache or nginx. I serve up my files with Create React Ap's npm run build.

Answer (score 0):

### Introduction

I was struggling with the same issue for days. It seems like there is a problem (also lack of documentation) on how to integrate Vercel and React backend. Below solution is working for my Vercel application.

*I am simply posting the solution from the original author who seems to have fixed their React application without updating this question.*

### Solution

Create a separate React application for the backend. Make sure to start with the backend and then add the frontend if it is still needed. You can follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BkVfnWxmQXo) YouTube as a template and move all backend files inside it. Then, **add a proxy** from your  frontend project to the newly created backend application to make it work in production.

### Proof

Click on the https://spotify-eight.vercel.app/ and right click to inspect the webpage. Go under **Network**, check **Preserve logs** and **Fetch/XHR**.

**Refresh the page**. You should now see a request called *artists*. Under **Headers** the requested URL is https://spotify-backend.vercel.app/artists. The author of the question has fixed the issue by creating another Vercel application. Visit the URL if you want to make sure the backend application is accessible from outside.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried:

```
app.get("*", function (req, res, next) {
        if (req.url.startsWith("/artists")) return next();
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../../../build"));
    });
```